# GhostscriptRasterizer - Everything bold and blurred

Tags: .net, ghostscript.net

I currently have the task that I have to print shipping labels that I get as PDF via C#. I use Ghostscript to split the PDF into individual pages and then print the images. This works very well, but I have the problem that everything is printed bold. This is especially a problem with the printed 2D barcodes, because then you can not read them.

Here is the Code I' using at the moment to create the Images:

```
int desired_dpi = 360;
using (var rasterizer = new GhostscriptRasterizer(Ghostscripts))
{       
      rasterizer.GraphicsAlphaBits = 0;
      rasterizer.TextAlphaBits = 0;
      var bytes = StaticHelper.ReadFully(inputFile);

      var path = Path.Combine(setting.DownloadFolder, Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".pdf");
      File.WriteAllBytes(path, bytes);
      rasterizer.Open(path);

      for (var pageNumber = 1; pageNumber <= rasterizer.PageCount; pageNumber++)
      {
             PrintInfo PrintInfo = new PrintInfo() { PDFFile = path };

             var pageFilePath = Path.Combine(setting.DownloadFolder, string.Format("Page-{0}-{1}.png", Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), pageNumber));

             var img = rasterizer.GetPage(desired_dpi, pageNumber);
             img.Save(pageFilePath, ImageFormat.Png);
             img.Dispose();
      }
      rasterizer.Close();
}
```

As you can see a already played with GraphicsAlphaBits / TextAlphaBits and sets them to 0 and I changed the DPI. But nothing worked the Bold will not go away.

as it should be

[image]

as it is

[image]

By the way, when I send the PDF directly to the printer, it prints correctly.

Anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: You're going to have to share the input PDF file before anyone can help. The TextAlphaBits and GraphicsAlphaBits should be 1, not 0, if you don't want anti-aliasing. Or just leave them at the default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like interpolation issue. By default GhostscriptRasterizer adds -dDOINTERPOLATE parameter which you can override (turn it off) by adding -dNOINTERPOLATE custom switch before opening GhostscriptRasterizer like this:

```
int desired_dpi = 360;
using (var rasterizer = new GhostscriptRasterizer(Ghostscripts))
{       
      var bytes = StaticHelper.ReadFully(inputFile);

      var path = Path.Combine(setting.DownloadFolder, Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".pdf");
      File.WriteAllBytes(path, bytes);

      rasterizer.CustomSwitches.Add("-dNOINTERPOLATE");    // >>>>> custom switch 

      rasterizer.Open(path);

      for (var pageNumber = 1; pageNumber <= rasterizer.PageCount; pageNumber++)
      {
             PrintInfo PrintInfo = new PrintInfo() { PDFFile = path };

             var pageFilePath = Path.Combine(setting.DownloadFolder, string.Format("Page-{0}-{1}.png", Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), pageNumber));

             var img = rasterizer.GetPage(desired_dpi, pageNumber);
             img.Save(pageFilePath, ImageFormat.Png);
             img.Dispose();
      }
      rasterizer.Close();
}
```